# pyspark streaming from kinesis kills heap

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, iot, amazon-kinesis

Running a sample application streaming data from kinesis. I did not get why this application uses so much heap and crashes.

Here is the code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kinesis import KinesisUtils, InitialPositionInStream
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime

# function declaration
def isDfEmpty(df):

    try:
        if not df.take(1) :
            return True

    except Exception as e:
        return True

    return False

# function declaration
def mergeTable(df):
    print("b:mergeTable")
    print(str(datetime.now()))

    try:
        global refDf

        if isDfEmpty(df) :
            print("no record, waiting !")
        else :
            if(isDfEmpty(refDf)) :
                refDf = df
            else :
                print("        before count %s" % refDf.count())
                refDf = df.unionAll(refDf)
                print("        after count %s" % refDf.count())

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(str(datetime.now()))
    print("e:mergeTable")   

# function declaration
def doWork(df):
    print("b:doWork")
    print(str(datetime.now()))

    try:
        mergeTable(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(str(datetime.now()))
    print("e:doWork")

# function declaration
def sensorFilter(sensorType, rdd):
    df = spark.read.json(rdd.filter(lambda x : sensorType in x))
    doWork(df)


def printRecord(rdd):
    print("========================================================")
    print("Starting new RDD")
    print("========================================================")
    sensorFilter("SensorData", rdd)

refDf = None    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reload(sys)  
    # sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')



    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
        print( "Usage: dump.py <app-name> <stream-name> <endpoint-url> <region-name>", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext

    # sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKinesisWordCountAsl")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
    appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName = sys.argv[1:]
    dstream = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 10)
    dstream.foreachRDD(printRecord)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

After a time the spark application slowed down due to heap usage. But when i comment out the lines, heap usage decrease to normal levels.(According to SparkUI)

```
print("        before count %s" % refDf.count())
print("        after count %s" % refDf.count())
```

I am really new with pyspark and trying to get what is going on. 
Merging on data frame continuously may explode the memory of course but the problem of heap occurs very beginning.

EDIT
Environment : Tried on single ubuntu and on cents VM hosted by macOS nothing changed.

Comment: Action operations `count()` bring entire data to your driver node and you are repeatedly performing them again and again. Does that tell you anything? Take a look at how large `refDf`  can get and compare with your drive/local machine's capacity.

Comment: I got your point @Pushkr as i mentioned on my note at the end. But be sure that it does not wait refDf to get as big as you expected. The heap explodes even really with small amounts.

Comment: Your batchinterval in StreamingContext must be in millis. If you want in seconds,  write Seconds(10) instead.